# Grafana Clustering for Alerting

Tags: grafana

We wanted to understand what were challenges with regards to clustering for Alerting in Grafana.

Grafana documentation mentions this at  http://docs.grafana.org/alerting/rules,

> Clustering¶
>   We have not implemented clustering yet. So if you run multiple instances of     grafana-server you have to make sure execute_alerts is true on only one instance or otherwise you will get duplicated notifications.

1. Do we know what is the roadmap for Grafana to support clustering for alerting? (or where can we find it).
2. What were the challenges Grafana had with clustering alerting? (there should have been something other than just duplicate notifications, otherwise, they would have done in first place)﻿

Answer (score 2):

1. Support for clustering is in the roadmap.
2. No specific challenges more than time to implement and wanting to get it out to users as soon as possible. Figured clustering could wait a bit